# Object is Invalid or Deleted when pressing button and plotting

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

Please help. The error says that the object is deleted.

> Error using handle.handle/get
> Invalid or deleted object.
>
> Error in C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2011b\toolbox\matlab\graph2d\plotyy.p>localUpdatePosition (line 373)
>
> Error in C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2011b\toolbox\matlab\graph2d\plotyy.p>@(obj,evd (localUpdatePosition(obj,evd,ax(1),ax(2))) (line 212)

I really do not understand what was deleted but every time I perform the impz(signal), the plot isn't showing the correct graph unlike the plot in freqz(signal) and zplane(signal).

This is what really happens (26seconds video) - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HTR45lNIjuc

Line 212 contains this code `handles.N = str2num(get(handles.edtOrder,'String'));`
Line 373 contains this code `zplane(handles.axPlots,handles.firVector,1)`

Code for impulse response

```
if (get(handles.cbImpResp,'Value') == 1)
        set(handles.txtPlotAvail,'Visible','off');
        switch (handles.filterValue)
            case 'FIR'
                impz(handles.axPlots,handles.firVector,1)
            case 'IIR'
                impz(handles.axPlots,handles.vectorB,handles.vectorA)
            case 'Multiple Bandpass'
        end
    else
        set(handles.txtPlotAvail,'Visible','on');
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The code is either mixing up your handles or overwriting old ones. There no way to debug this without the full source.
See http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/85117

Comment: I don't see any code mixing up. Anyway, here's the full source. http://pastebin.com/XWUbJux9

Comment: no .fig gui file >_<
why is 354 uncommented but 310 isnt? (`cla` commands after pbPrev and pbNext)
are you sure you want to use reset here? are the conditionals at 311 and 355 correct?

Comment: .fig file: http://www.mediafire.com/download/odd3b4abccw2oto/Mod3.fig
.m file: http://www.mediafire.com/view/spgndmadn5hklt2/Mod3.m

I uploaded the codes that is not updated. Here's the updated one. P.S. There are functions included in the .m File but its corresponding object in .fig does not exist. I also edited the code in the link above.